# Convert Number to Lakhs using Custom Number format

Tags: excel

I want to convert numbers to Lakhs with two decimals using Custom Number format in EXCEL.
For example.

- 6,27,325   output  6.27
- 6,27,526  output 6.28

Here I wrote the following formula in CUSTOM NUMBER FORMAT (right click chosen FORMAT CELLS ...> NUMBER...> CUSTOM)...

```
#\.#####
```

It displays 6.27325, 6.27526
But my need is 6.27 and 6.28 value should be rounded, and two decimals allow only.
Moreover, I would like to use CUSTOM NUMBER FORMAT only.
No EXCEL functions or VBA.

Comment: CUSTOM NUMBER FORMAT (FORMAT CELLS ...> NUMBER tab...> CUSTOM)... #.##

Comment: @Solar Mike .. I didn't get it... ??

Comment: As far as I know, formatting rules applies standard rounding rules. Besides, formatting affects only what you see, but the real value of the cell will not be altered at all. Are you sure you don't need any function for this?

Comment: @Foxfire Burns... nice to listen you. I would like display the values using only Customer Number format.  if any ideas regarding this  welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following for this:

```
##\.##,
```

The single comma at the end of the entire string resolves out the "thousands" as it might be called in the US. So `###,` would format 843,187 as 843. In the US, we would typically add a letter "K" to the end so it reads 843K indicating 843 thousand and meaning "the thousands digits are just there to make it confusing so they are not shown and the last digit is rounded using '4/5' rounding so this number could be any value from 842,500 through 843,499, inclusive" (the "K" stands for thousands... if one were doing this for millions, one would use "M" in its display and TWO bare commas at the end of the format).

(In reality, said so or not, one is really suppressing the "under a single thousand" digits. We just say it that way because the lowest digit that is left is the thousands digit, and then we get imprecise when expanding the saying of it to describing the ones/tens/hundreds digits that are now gone.)

In any case, Lahk does the same thing, for part of its display:  it suppresses the digits for values below 1,000. So you can use this same technique as it does the same thing. That leaves you with only the digits needed to express Lahk.

However, it leaves you with "628" not "6.28" and I cannot find a direct way to force proper display. I did once using the percentage formatting in combination with the bare comma at the end, but am at work and do not have time to work that out again. The percentage operator inside a number format can work similarly to the bare commas in that it can suppress batches of characters, two at a time, the way the bare commas do, three at a time. But... it might be just the suppressing though memory says it helped in grouping them as well. So you looking into that yourself might or might not lead to something useful.

Instead, the above format does nothing elegant:  it just "brute forces" the idea. It uses the `#` characters so that only needed digits will be shown (so no "04.23" outputs, rather "4.23" instead), but you seem familiar with that. It uses `##` at the start to accomodate 0.xx-99.xx lahk, then forces a `.` character into the string using the comma character preceded by the backslash character;  `\.`, and finally, finishes with two places for two decimal digits.

Note that this has the weakness that it will ALWAYS give two decimal places, so always "6.00" lahk and never "6" lahk. You seem to be following a non-traditional approach here as you want "6.27" and not "6,27" so one suspects you won't mind this. It happens due to the use of the bare comma at the end, so using `?` characters instead of `#` characters does not help.

To get the "6,27" style just force a comma instead of a period at position three (places 3-4) of the format string.